# What looks like a str, acts like a str, but isn't a str?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a situation where var is returned from an external function that gets variables out of API POST requests. In this case I have made it 'hello world'.

```
a='hello world'
print a, isinstance(a, str)
print var, isinstance(var, str)
```

Console:

```
hello world True
hello world False
```

What behaves like an str but isn't?

---

Another case, concatenation works:

```
a = 'hello world'
var += '!'
print a, isinstance(a, str)
print var, isinstance(var, str)
```

Console:

```
hello world True
hello world! False
```

---

Asking for the type

```
print type(var)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/will/env/feed/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/will/env/feed/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/will/env/feed/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 29, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/will/env/feed/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 57, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/will/env/feed/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 25, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/will/local/feed/src/fAPI/base.py", line 178, in dispatch
    return self.post()
  File "/home/will/local/feed/src/ublog/api.py", line 91, in post
    message = self.get_BODY_safe('message', 1)
  File "/home/will/local/feed/src/fAPI/base.py", line 141, in get_BODY_safe
    print type(var)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Why don't you do `type(var)` and find out?

Comment: Issue with that too, will add to question

Comment: Perhaps `var` is an object of some class

Comment: You have a variable named `type`

Comment: Somewhere you have `type = 1`, do `from __builtin__ import type as type_func; type_func(var)`

Comment: @will: you bound `type` to an integer. Use `del type` or `import __builtin__; `__builtin__.type(var)`.

Comment: Oh deary dear, thanks buddy, it's far too early in the week

Comment: var is `<type 'unicode'>`

Comment: Well that answers your question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many types that are like strings, maybe `bytearray` or `unicode`.

```
>>> t = str('abcde')
>>> isinstance(t, str)
True
>>> isinstance(t, bytearray)
False
>>> isinstance(t, unicode)
False
>>> t = bytearray('abcde')
>>> isinstance(t, str)
False
>>> isinstance(t, unicode)
False
>>> isinstance(t, bytearray)
True
```

If you want to know which type are you dealing with, use function `type`

```
>>> t = bytearray('abcde')
>>> type(t)
<type 'bytearray'>
```

Answer (score 4):

You've already discovered that the variable is actually unicode. Python 2 has a base type that combines both of these types, which you can use in isinstance: `basestring`.

```
>>> isinstance('foo', basestring)
True

> isinstance(u'foo', basestring)
True
```